# Why my test_index is empty when I try to stratified it?

Tags: scikit-learn

Im trying Stratified kfold validation. But my test_index, and test variable is empty. What Im doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()

x = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
y = pd.DataFrame(data.target)

skf = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=5)

fold_no = 1
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x, y):
    print(test_index)
    train = x.loc[train_index,:]
    test = x.loc[test_index]

    # ratio = sum(test)/len(test)

    print('Fold {}, Class Ratio: {}'.format(fold_no, ratio))
    fold_no += 1
```

OUTPUT:

[0]
Fold 1, Class Ratio: 0.0
[]
Fold 2, Class Ratio: 0.0
[]
Fold 3, Class Ratio: 0.0
[]
Fold 4, Class Ratio: 0.0
[]
Fold 5, Class Ratio: 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using groups, you should use [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) instead:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd

data = load_breast_cancer()

x = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
y = pd.DataFrame(data.target)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

fold_no = 1
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x, y):
    # print(test_index)
    train = x.loc[train_index,:]
    test = x.loc[test_index]

    ratio = sum(test)/len(test)

    print('Fold {}, Class Ratio: {}'.format(fold_no, ratio))
    fold_no += 1
```

Output:

```py
Fold 1, Class Ratio: 3.8157894736842106
Fold 2, Class Ratio: 3.8157894736842106
Fold 3, Class Ratio: 3.8157894736842106
Fold 4, Class Ratio: 3.8157894736842106
Fold 5, Class Ratio: 3.849557522123894.
```

If you plan on using groups, you need to specify it:

```py
skf = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=5)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x, y, groups):
    ...
```

groups being the list of group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into train/test set. (see [StratifiedGroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html)).